# What is the best way to format an edit box that represents a numeric value?

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, devexpress, editbox

In my c# program I have a very simple DevExpress edit box that represents a numeric value.

[image]

What I would like to do is to add a restriction on the number of decimals in such a way that:

- Users cannot type, paste or in any other way enter a value that contains more than a predefined number of decimals. I fact I just want to editbox to ignore the user's typing as soon as 3 decimals have been entered.
- If a programmer sets the edit box' text, the value is rounded so that it meets the requirements.

What is the best way to do this?

Ps.: I thought this would solve my problem:

```
valueTextEdit.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
valueTextEdit.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "#.000;[#.000];0.000";
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. I can still enter values with 10 decimals. Also in code I can set the edit box text to a value with a larger number of decimals.

Comment: Try setting the decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true`:

Have a look [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsMaskMaskProperties_UseMaskAsDisplayFormattopic) and [here](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/85521/292827.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Nice example [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1498)

Answer (score 0):

try this
MaskTextBox control of .Net

you can use MaskedTextBox for entering data in numeric format in text box.

i hope this will help you

thank you

Comment: The MaskTextBox is interesting, I did not know this. However I cannot use a non-DevExpress control because I use the DevExpress validation thing to validate the edit box value (e.g. for validating that it lies within a certain range).

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own class that derives (inherits) from `TextBox`, then override property `Text` to add your requirments:

```
internal class SmartTextBox : TextBox
{
    public SmartTextBox()
    {
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            // validate 'value' before setting it
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

After you build your project, you will find your new `Control` called `SmartTextBox` with .NET Controls.

**EDIT:** However, if you use `TextBox` for numeric input only, why don't you use `NumericUpDown` Control? It is much better, users can not input characters and you can even set the precision of decimal number.

Comment: Is this property called with each keystroke?

Comment: @Ba yab. After any change in text, this `override` property will called, so that you can always validate input.